# Crystal Report: how to use sum(column) as column as in mysql query

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

I have a table named browse with the following structure:

```
Outlet--MenuType--Value  
X-------Food---------100  
X-------Food---------200  
Y-------Liquor-------100  
X-------Liquor-------300 and so on...
```

I want the output of crystal report as follows:

```
X  

---Food--- 300  
---Liquor--300  
-------------600  

Y  
--Liquor---100  
-------------100
```

Grouping is to be done based on Outlet Name and then subtotaling all menutype values of each outlet. Which is not the issue. But the issue is how to have the effect of sum(Value) as Value in the report. I want food,liquor to be written only once for each outlet.

Answer (score 0):

What I am getting is-

```
select Outlet, MenuType, sum(Value) as Value from browse group by Outlet, MenuType;
```

Do you want something else ?

Comment: yes i want to do this but through crystal report using report expert. I have figured out the solution to my problem by taking menugroup also in group by field. thank you.